# Custom Method Sorting Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

is there possibility to use Java method to sort JPA result?

I have entity:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Name   | Latitude | Longitude |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| A      | x1       | y1        |
| B      | x2       | y2        |
| C      | x3       | y3        |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

I mean instead of writing SQL:

```
    "  ORDER BY (acos(sin(latitude * $RADIAN) * sin(:latitude * $RADIAN)" +
    "       + cos(latitude * $RADIAN) * cos(:latitude * $RADIAN)" +
    "         * cos((:longitude * $RADIAN) - (longitude * $RADIAN))" +
    "  ) * $EARTH_RADIUS)")
fun findDoctorDepartmentsInRange(@Param("latitude") latitude: Double,
                                 @Param("longitude") longitude: Double)
```

I've tried with [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) but how to inject custom java method into EXPRESSION used below:

```
query.orderBy(cb.asc(EXPRESSION))
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert for EXPRESSION `root.get("yourFieldName")` ?

Comment: without a definition of what is "a", "b", "x" nobody can tell you. You cannot use a Java method in generated SQL (which is what JPA Criteria generates) also. PS that SQL you quote is invalid ... the ASC comes at the end.

Comment: Update: I described my problem more precisely.

Comment: Since there are no JPQL functions `COS`, `SIN`, etc then you need to make use of JPQL / Criteria `function` for each of those native SQL function calls. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_functions_other

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring JPA, you could use `Sort` object, and you append it not in your specification but to your query

as far as i remember sntax will be something like that

```
repository.findAll(specification,  new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "field"));
```

**Edit**

I'm not sure is `Sort` supports expressions, so if you want to do this in java code, you need to create Criteria API query, which will be something like that

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SomeClass> query = cb.createQuery(SomeClass.class);
Root<SomeClass> root = query.from(SomeClass.class);
Expression EXPRESSION = <<TypeYourExpression>>;
query.orderBy(cb.asc(EXPRESSION))
query.where(specification.toPredicate(root,query,cb))
List<SomeClass> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes but I want to use method instead of String

Comment: @NorbertNowak in this case you might need to extend your repository and build custom criteria api query, and then you will have access to `query` hence ou will be able to provide `expression`

Comment: @NorbertNowak it's possible, but what you need is to use criteria api to build query, i will edit m answer and explain you in details

Comment: its helpful but actually I haven't found any way to create sort Expression

Comment: @NorbertNowak given complexity of your expression, i woud define it as DB function and cal it by `cb.function("SORT_EXPR_FNAME", Double.class,root.get("latitude"),root.get("longtitude"))` which will return you `Expression<Double>` don't guarantee you it will work, but you can try. alternativly you could use `function to call build in trigonometry functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have java code as your `ORDER BY` expression in general. Not in SQL nor in JPA.

Some databases (at least Oracle) allow you to define Stored Procedures in Java, so in theory, you probably can write an SP in Java and use the that in an `ORDER BY` expression.